# Why Visual Studio 2013 and Qt5 addin are always updating .vcxproj.user file?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, qt5, project-settings

I create simple Qt5 application project in VS2013, this project is accompanied by .vcxproj.user file which contains QTDIR path variable and initialization for

LocalDebuggerEnvironment = PATH=$(QTDIR)\bin%3b$(PATH).

The problem arises when I am modifying the .vcxproj.user file either in VS2013 or outside

(e.g., LocalDebuggerEnvironment = PATH=$(QTDIR)\bin%3b$(VTKDIR)%3b$(PATH)).

Each time I restart VS2013 the .vcxproj.user file is reset and the modifications are lost... How one can fix this reset (after restarting VS2013) in order to keep the modifications done in .vcxproj.user file? Thx!

Comment: Why do you want to change it?

Comment: I need the project Debug run-time sees VTK DLLs being run in VS2013.

Comment: Turn on the read-only attribute on the file, some odds that the evil-doer is going to say Bang! when it tries to modify it.

Comment: Read-only attribute on does the business, VS2013 is Banging now but doing well :) Thx Hans! All in all one has to keep it in head the attribute might cause the project compilation failure...